# Sitecore 9.1 update 1 installation error with Azure SQL database

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, installation

I'm trying to install `Sitecore 9.1 update 1` with `Azure SQL database as a service, I'm getting below error. Please help.

```
> [---------------------------------- XConnectXP0_InstallWDP : WebDeploy
> -----------------------------------------------] [WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe msdeploy.exe
> : Error Code: ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE At C:\Program
> Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.1.0\Public\Tasks\Invoke-CommandTask.ps1:31
> char:13
> +             & $Path $Arguments | Out-Default
> +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error Code: ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE:String) [], RemoteException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   More Information: An error occurred during execution of the database script. The error
> occurred between the following  lines of the script: "1" and "3". The
> verbose log might have more information about the error. The command
> started  with the following: "e xec sp_configure 'contained database
> authenticati"  Could not find stored procedure 'sp_configure'.
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587  Learn more at: 
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE.
> 
> Error: Could not find stored procedure 'sp_configure'.
> 
> Error count: 1.
> 
> Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft
> Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero  exit code - (-1) At
> C:\Source Files\XP0 Configuration files 9.1.1 rev.
> 002459\XP0-SingleDeveloper-non-signed.ps1:74 char:1
> + Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Objec ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
> [TIME] 00:15:15
```

Comment: Take a look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53884508/azuresql-could-not-find-stored-procedure-sp-configure-while-installing-siteco

Comment: I think you missed `Stored Procedure` with the name `sp_configure` ?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem.. I am also installing vanilla Sitecore 9.0 onprim with Azure Sql Server and facing same issue. From @Chris solution I am not able to point to the link so complete steps are not there

Answer (score 4):

I don't want this to be a link only answer, but I have several IaaS installs using Azure SQL as the database. You need to extract the user creation SQL scripts from the SIF scwsp files, modify them and then repackage the scwsp files.

You can follow the steps here to repackage the sql scripts you need for Azure SQL.

http://www.chrissulham.com/modify-sitecore-install-framework-packages-for-azure-sql/

Also in the `xconnect-xp0.json` file, you need to change `Sharding.DacPac.Path` to point at azure file and not the normal SQL path.

`Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.Sql.dacpac`

becomes

`Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.Sql.Azure.dacpac`

The full like is:

```
"Sharding.DacPac.Path": "[joinpath(variable('Sharding.Root.Path'), 'Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.Sql.dacpac')]",
```

to

```
"Sharding.DacPac.Path": "[joinpath(variable('Sharding.Root.Path'), 'Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.Sql.Azure.dacpac')]",
```

Comment: thank you very much! This is really what I was looking for. I will accept this as answer if that's work out.

Comment: Can you please share the link again because above mentioned link is not working..What are the files you extracted from package link is not working.. and what are changes you applied to those files. I am also facing same issue.. I am installing Sitecore 9.0 with Azure Sql Server where sp_configure is not available..

Answer (score 0):

sp_configure is only available on managed instance, it's not available on Azure SQL Database.

To fix this issue try creating contained database users on Azure SQL Database.

Comment: I'm installing vanilla Sitecore 9.1.1 instance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Peter. We can not execute sp_configure with Contained Database option in current Azure SQL Database.

Approach of Deployment should be

1. Full on Premise Deployment
2. IaaS (Infrastructure As A Service)
3. Sitecore in Azure App Service. (PaaS)